# How to convert compressed (high-order byte removed) bytes to Unicode string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unicode, character-encoding

I have a string represented as an array of bytes that I know have had the high-order byte of `0x00` removed, such that the string is compressed as:

```
0x43 0x6F 0x6D 0x6D 0x61 0x6E 0x64 //"Command"
```

How can I convert the bytes to a Unicode string?

I'm guessing I need to copy the bytes into a new array (`uncompressedBytes`) that is twice the size, at every second interval:

```
byte[] compressedBytes = br.ReadBytes(stringLength);
byte[] uncompressedBytes = new byte[stringLength * 2];
for (int byteCounter = 0; byteCounter < stringLength; byteCounter++)
{
    uncompressedBytes[byteCounter * 2] = compressedBytes[byteCounter];
}
return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(uncompressedBytes);
```

Or is there an Encoding that will treat all the bytes as Unicode characters that are missing their high order byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first 256 code points were made identical to the content of ISO-8859-1 so as to make it trivial to convert existing western text.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the bytes are `0x7f` or less you can treat them as being `utf-8` and use the `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` converter class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't *know* that all the bytes are 0x7f or less.

Comment: Stripping off the high-order byte of larger Unicode values would corrupt the data. There is no compression in Unicode, and certainly not one that simply chops off bytes. So, if all the bytes are 0x7F and lower, you have ASCII, which is compatible with UTF-8. If you have any bytes between 0x80-0xFF then you are dealing with ANSI, most likely ISO-8859-1, but maybe Windows-1252 or other encoding, too